# HOW, Admin allow to show categories private and publicly in magento?

Tags: php, magento

in magento how to possible that some category   has to be a private and a public, wherein the private section can be viewed only by logged in users i.e. some tabs can be viewed only by logged in users. the users can register and the admin can only grant them access..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is a extension for this type of problem.

> http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vinai/extension/635/netzarbeiter_groupscatalog#tab:reviews

Answer (score 0):

I would make a module to override the category controller and put a restriction there based on a category attribute that would be added by the same module.

The attribute would be a yes/no on restricted. Given the attribute, the visitor must be a customer.

However, most of the clients I have dealt with usually just start up a new website with website restrictions and put their restricted catagories there. (like a B2B site or something)

Comment: To answer admin granting access, the customer would need to register, be automatically put in the general customer group, then the admin would have to put them in the special restricted access customer group. Then the category controller override would only let customers in that group through.